# is there any other method than .isSelected() to check if radio button is selected

Tags: java, netbeans

i am helping my friend  on a project

i have tried to add aditional events between the if statements but when i add them it seems top wrok properly is there any way to check is the radio button is selected as .isChecked doesn 't work for some weird reason

```java
 private void btnPreveriMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        String compare = lblVprasanje.getText();
        if (compare.equals("question")) {
            if (rbtOdgovor3.isSelected()) {
        new Correct().setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            } else {
                new Wrong().setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }

        }

        if (compare.equals("hello")) {
            if (rbtOdgovor2.isSelected()) {
                new Correct().setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            } else {
                new Wrong().setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }

        }

        if (compare.equals("question")) {
            new DrugaStopnja().setVisible(true);
            if (rbtOdgovor3.isSelected()) {
                new Correct().setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            } else {
                new Wrong().setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }

        }

        if (compare.equals("question")) {
            if (rbtOdgovor1.isSelected()) {
                new Correct().setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            } else {
                new Wrong().setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }

        }
```

well if the correct radio button is selected the "correct" window should open but if the wrong one is the "wrong " window should. I dont understand why the .isSelected() is not working

Comment: Did you check what is return of `lblVprasanje.getText()` add `System.out.println(lblVprasanje.getText()` at the start. I'm stating that maybe your `if` statement never has true

Comment: i tried that the first if is true defenetly apparently there were braces missing at init commponents